# C++ 20 template id issue

Tags: c++, gcc

I have this code that is compiling well using std=c++17.

Now after migrating to c++20.

I got an error.

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
   S<T>(){};
};
```

```
error expected unqualified-id before ')' token line 3
```

Is there a solution to avoid this issue without modifying the code because it belongs to an external lib ?

PS: gcc 11.1 is reporting the issue but not clang !!!

https://godbolt.org/z/svqY77WTP

Comment: The `<T>` in `S<T>` seems redundant to me. i.e. I would normally expect to see `S() {}` instead. Does it actually serve a purpose I'm not seeing here?

Comment: [10.3 compiles the code](https://godbolt.org/z/bozTG74fr) so you could down grade your compiler.

Comment: Cannot upgrade or downgrade. Because I'm depending on other projects..

Comment: This seems like a bug.

Comment: Concerning your (now deleted) question: Your link on Compiler Explorer used g++. Hence, this might be a start: [GNU Assembler Examples](https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/gasexamples/). (I just was about to post this link as your question vanished.) And yet another one: [Linux Assembly HOWTO](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/rhlinux/redhat-6.2-docs/HOWTOS/other-formats/pdf/Assembly-HOWTO.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a C++ problem, but rather the compiler. Gcc version 8.3 works fine as shown below.

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct S {
   S<T>(){};
};

int main() {
   std::cout << "hello\n";
}
$ g++ -std=c++2a test.cpp
$ $ ./a.out 
hello
$ g++ -v 2>&1 | grep "gcc version"
gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
```

Comment: There's no solution/workaround for it ?

Comment: gcc version 11 enforces a new constraint described here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html you have to update your code

Comment: The code is belonging to a third party library. It's not possible.

Comment: I guess you have to stick to gcc version 10 then.